# Scraping multiple tables in python efficiently

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-extraction

I am currently trying to scrape data from the https://essentialoils.org/db#. I am trying to use selenium, but it will take too long to scrape the needed data. I am eventually taking the data into two CSV files first with (Name, Latin Botanical, Citation, CAS) and then another (Essential oil, Ingredient name, Percentage, DB 5, Carbowax). If someone could help me by directing me the fastest way to do this it would be much help. Here is my current code and a couple of images.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxF30.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWKHX.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eQ8s.jpg

```
 #import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

#set up the driver for firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://essentialoils.org/auth/login")
# wait for page to load
sleep(1)
# select the username and password fields
username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
username.click()
# input the username
username.send_keys("email@email.com")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.click()
# input the password
password.send_keys("password")
# press the submit button
submit = driver.find_element_by_id("process_login")
submit.click()
# wait for 2 seconds
sleep(2)
# go to the database page
driver.get("https://essentialoils.org/db")
# wait for page to load
sleep(2)
# find table
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='item-table']/tbody")
# find all the td elements in the table
tds = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
# create a list of the td elements
names=[]
latin_name=[] 
citation=[]
cas=[]
# select the first td then skip 3 
for td in tds[0::3]:
    names.append(td.text)
print('Done collecting names')
for td in tds[1::3]:
    latin_name.append(td.text)
print('Done collecting latin names')
for td in tds[2::3]:
    citation.append(td.text)
print('Done collecting citation')
#click on each row to get data then go back
for id,td in enumerate(tds[0::3]):
    id = id+1
    if id == 4153:
        # stop and continue
        break
    else:
        print(f'{id} of 4152')
        x_path = f'//*[@id="item-table"]/tbody/tr[{id}]/td[1]'
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path).click()
        sleep(2)
        #find the element by class name and append to the list
        cas_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eoudb"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span')
        cas.append(cas_number.text[5:])
        #go back to the table url db wait to load
        driver.get("https://essentialoils.org/db")
        sleep(5)
# create pandas dataframe with column names Name,Latin Botanical,Citation,CAS
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': names,
        'Latin Botanical': latin_name,
        'Citation': citation,
        'CAS': cas
    }
)
# save the dataframe to a csv file
df.to_csv('essential_oils.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: So what is your exact problem?

Comment: It would take probably 8 to 9 hours to get the CAS number with having selenium click on a row get the data, go back, and repeat. I was curious if there was a faster way to get the data in half the time. I haven't tried to get the data from the inner table yet.

Comment: (1) never use implicit wait with selenium like sleep(), it's not useful and may throw annoying errors, use explicit wait instead, you import WebDriverWait but never used. the sleep (7) inside the for loop may be too long, if you have to repeat 100 times it will be more than 10 minutes of waiting. (2) i don't know how big the tds list is, if it's really big use list comprehension instead of .append() method since is really faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much faster using Requests and BeautifulSoup. I'm not going to post my cookie information, however if you go to the network tab on your browser, you can see what headers are being used for the request.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import requests
import json

cookies = {
    'XSRF-TOKEN': '',
    'laravel_session': '',
    '_pk_id.1.5d5e': '',
    '_pk_ses.1.5d5e': '*',
    '_ga': '',
    '_gid': '',
    '__stripe_sid': '',
    '__stripe_mid': '',
    'laravel_token': '',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_118297571_1': '1',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'CHANGE FOR YOUR TOKEN',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://essentialoils.org/db',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

response = requests.get('https://essentialoils.org/api/oil?fields=id,name,name_sort,CAS,abstract_publication,name_botanical,name_botanical_sort&pages=*&reset_cache&synonym', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
json_ptag = soup.select_one('p').text.strip()
json_text = json.loads(json_text)

print(json_text)
```

This returns a list of dictionaries, one is displayed below:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Abies alba from cones', 'name_sort': 'ABIESALBAFROMCONES', 'CAS': '8021-27-0', 'abstract_publication': 'Riechstoffe, Aromen, Koerperpflegemittel, Vol. 18, 376 (1968) ', 'name_botanical': 'Abies alba Mill., fam. Pinaceae', 'name_botanical_sort': 'ABIES ALBA MILL., FAM. PINACEAE'}
```

Comment: Okay I tried this and entered my cookie information, but I got {"success":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Unauthenticated."}} response is [501]

Comment: I figured it out I guess my tokens had changed. I just have to make sure I double-check them.